# RestKit: Unique constrians in CoreData is not updating the exisiting entry

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, unique-constraint, restkit-0.26.x

I've integrated RestKit for my iOS project in Swift 3. I have multiple entities and they have multiple relationships between them. Now I have added Unique constraint for particular entity and want to update the exisiting entity every time there is new data with unique constrians. So for that I have added merge policy to ObjectTrumpMergePolicy

```
managedObjectContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
```

But the data in entity doesn't get updated.
I have checked that core data entry over writes exisiting entry if I directly use the core data without RestKit. But I don't know why it is not updating when I am doing this using RestKit.
Please anyone help me out of this.